# asp.net c# .net framework 2.0 and 3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, frameworks

We have a asp.net application built in .net framework 2.0.
I need to edit a web report and add few columns to the report.
I updated the aspx.cs file and uploaded it to the server but there is no change in the report. If I change aspx file it works but aspx.cs file changes are not reflecting on the server. And I dont have local setup of the application to check.
Is it necessary to compile the file, but same thing I have done with framework 4.5 without compiling and it worked. How can I update the report without compiling the file.

Comment: The code behind (cs file) is compiled into a DLL you have to upload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In server it executes only compiled code, if you upload .cs files, it will affect nothing, so you need to upload compiled code(.dll) to see the changes.

Comment: I have just copied aspx.cs file from the server and updated it. How do I convert it to dll and after converting it to dll what changes need to be made to aspx file. As the application is running, I dont want to disturb the users.@Supraj-v

Comment: You need to compile your project and publish the project to a folder..and then replace the contents(DLL) in bin folder to server folder

Answer (score 1):

you need to publish the new .dll file found in the bin directory to the remote locations bin folder.

If youre publishing through VS which I suspect your not, this would do this automatically on publish.

If youre doing what I think your doing and copying and pasting you need to copy the bin directory up too.

There are a number of files \ folders that you need but the aspx.cs files are not any of them.

Answer (score 1):

In ASP.NET when you place the aspx and aspx.cs file the files get complied automatically before the execution by ASP.NET engine. Please check the updated code does it contain any reference from 4.5 library.Additionally you can try to referesh the IIS cache sometimes ASP.Net engine unable to refresh/replce the existing files in the cache folder.